# Pthread Synchronization: Back & Forth Reading of Two Text Files

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

I'm writing a program that creates two threads. Each thread is responsible for reading through one text file, with one char on each line.

The first is formatted like:

```
h
0
h
0
...
```

The second is formatted like:

```
0
i
0
i
0
i
```

Sometimes there can be multiple letters after each other, or multiple zeros after each other. However, the one certainty is that if there is a letter on one line of one file, the corresponding line of the second file will have a 0, and vice versa.

The threads are supposed to keep reading the file input into a global char array until they reach a zero. At this point, they allow the other thread to take over. And they keep going back and forth until both files are completely read.

At this point, when I run, I get variations of either (1) many h's followed by many i's or (2) (**the correct answer**) a continuous stream of hihihi's, or (3) sometimes many i's followed by many h's. So, I know that my synchronization methods are off.

Here is an example of one of my threads:
(Note both threads are exactly the same, except for the file being opened.)

```
void *getMessage1()
{
FILE *studentOne = fopen("Student1", "r");

size_t howManyChars;
char *placeHolderChars; 
int count = 1;
while (count < 501)
{
    placeHolderChars = NULL;
    getline(&placeHolderChars, &howManyChars, studentOne);

    if(strcmp(placeHolderChars, "0\n") == 0) //if we've reached a zero
    {

         pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); 
    }
    else
    {   while(1)
        {
            if(pthread_mutex_trylock(&lock) == 0)
            {

                break;
            }
        }

        if(strlen(placeHolderChars)>0)
        {
             placeHolderChars[1] = '\0';
        }

        strcat(message,placeHolderChars);
    }

    free(placeHolderChars);

    if(feof(studentOne))
    {

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); //unlock
        fclose(studentOne);
        break;
    }
    count++;

 }

return 0;
}
```

Here is my main method:

```
int main(void)
{
pthread_t id1;
pthread_t id2;

pthread_create((&id1), NULL, getMessage1, NULL);
pthread_create((&id2), NULL, getMessage2, NULL);

pthread_join(id1, NULL);
pthread_join(id2, NULL);

int j;

for (j = 0; j < 1001; j++) 
{
     printf ("%c ",message[j]);
}

return 0;
}
```

**I would appreciate any guidance on how I can better use lock, unlock, wait, and/or signal to create a working synchronization technique with consistent results.**

Comment: Semaphores.  You cannot do this with a mutex.  Multi-dupe.

Comment: My professor actually suggested that we use mutex, since he claimed it would make it much easier. So, should i scrap the mutex and use a binary semaphore or something?

Comment: Also, should I consider only having one function, which both threads use? (And then they pass the file as a parameter?) Would that make any difference?

Comment: Is there no way to do this with a mutex?

Comment: I'm not sure what a semaphore will do here that mutex can't - a mutex is essentially a semaphore that can only have a count of 0 or 1.  A possibly more appropriate synchronization object to use is a condition variable (which also requires a mutex). Perhaps most importantly, it looks like the mutex is misused. For example, if the first line of either file is "0", the thread the reads that line will unlock the mutex even though it hasn't locked it.

Comment: by condition variable, do you mean wait & signal in pthread? I tried using them, without success. But, I'll try again(using them differently) and see what happens. Deadlock tends to occur when I use wait, which I'm assuming means that I'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: one question I had was: why is it incorrect to call signal before you call wait? (like waking the other thread up before you put yourself to sleep)?

Comment: I would say the standard PThreads way of doing this is with a condition variable. Read the manpages, e.g. pthread_cond_init, pthread_cond_destroy, pthread_cond_signal, pthread_cond_broadcast, pthread_cond_wait, pthread_cond_timedwait. On *buntu and probably on Debian as well, do sudo apt install glibc-doc first.

Comment: @MichaelBurr 'a mutex is essentially a semaphore that can only have a count of 0 or 1' no, it is not.  A mutex can only be released by the thread that acquired it,

Comment: Please do not destroy the information in a question, especially not after it has an answer.

Comment: The same OP also asked [Using both condition variable and mutexes to synchronize threads in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386600/using-both-conditional-variables-mutex-to-synchronize-threads-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one attempt at a program that does what you want. Insufficiently tested, though ;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <cassert>
#include <pthread.h>



using std::cout;
using std::ifstream;
using std::string;

const string FILE1("file1.txt");
const string FILE2("file2.txt");

enum State
{
    UNINITIALIZED,
    THREAD_ONE_READS,
    THREAD_TWO_READS
};

struct ThreadInfo
{
    State state;
    string filename;
};

State state = UNINITIALIZED;
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void* thread_func(void* arg)
{
    // Open file 'h'.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    ThreadInfo ti = *reinterpret_cast<ThreadInfo*>(arg);
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open (ti.filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);

    // while (not EOF)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    //    Read 'h' or 'i': until 0 reached. Wake up other thread.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

    string line;
    getline(infile, line);
    while (infile.good())
    {
        cout << "Thread " << pthread_self() << " read " << line << '\n';
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        while (state == ti.state)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mut);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);

        assert(line.length() == 1);
        if (line[0] == '0')
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
            state = ti.state;
            cout << "Got 0, transferring, setting state to " << state << '\n';
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Read char: " << line << '\n';
        }
        getline(infile, line);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    state = ti.state;
    cout << "Finishing thread, transferring, setting state to " << state << '\n';
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
}

int main()
{
    // Create thread 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    // Create thread 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    pthread_t thread_one_handle;
    pthread_t thread_two_handle;
    state = THREAD_ONE_READS;
    int result;

    ThreadInfo info1 = { THREAD_TWO_READS, FILE1 };
    result = pthread_create(&thread_one_handle, NULL, thread_func, &info1);
    assert(result == 0);

    ThreadInfo info2 = { THREAD_ONE_READS, FILE2 };
    result = pthread_create(&thread_two_handle, NULL, thread_func, &info2);
    assert(result == 0);

    result = pthread_join(thread_one_handle, NULL);
    assert(result == 0);
    result = pthread_join(thread_two_handle, NULL);
    assert(result == 0);
    cout << "main(): joined both worker threads, ending program.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Selena Did this help? I saw you posted the same question twice and accepted the answer for the other, equivalent question ;(

Comment: I observe that this question was always tagged with only C and never C++, but this answer is in C++.  This probably limits its usefulness to the OP.  I've also noted the other question by the same OP on the same topic (in a comment at the top).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Since use of C++-specific features are very limited in my answer, translating to old-skool C should be trivial.